# VS2012 Experimental hive's 11.0Exp_Config location

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I've migrated my VS extension from VS2010 to 2012 today, and when debugging the extension via the experimental hive, it seems to be creating a new registry entry for the _Config directory, with new number every time, e.g.:

> `HKCI\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0Exp_Config_12944`

I assumed the later was the process ID for the new devenv.exe instance, but it isn't.

I have some custom code that needs to read a value from this config dir, I use `__VSSPROPID.VSSPROPID_VirtualRegistryRoot` to get the registry root:

```
object property;
 _vsShell.GetProperty((int)__VSSPROPID.VSSPROPID_VirtualRegistryRoot, out property);
return property.ToString();
```

I would simply append "_Config" to the property value, but now it seems that it's not the case anymore.

Is there either a way to prevent VS2012 experimental hive appending that number, and just use 11.0Exp_Config, or is there a way (API, flag) to retrieve the config registry root?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ilocalregistry4.getlocalregistryrootex(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, it indeed solved my issue! If you'd like, add your answer, and I'll accept it!

Comment: Your answer looks fine to me, I can't improve it.

Comment: @HansPassant further investigation led me to the VSRegistry class, already wrapping this nicely in an API that even returns a RegistryKey! I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Hans' comment above, I was able to solve the problem using [`ILocalRegistry4.GetLocalRegistryRootEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ilocalregistry4.getlocalregistryrootex.aspx), passing in the [`__VsLocalRegistryType.RegType_Configuration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vslocalregistrytype.aspx) enum.

// previous code deleted

**EDIT:** Upon further investigation, there seems to be a much better way - a class that already does this, accepting  `__VsLocalRegistryType` as parameter: [`VSRegistry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsregistry.aspx), also conveniently returning `RegistryKey`:

```
public RegistryKey ConfigRoot
{
    get { return VSRegistry.RegistryRoot(__VsLocalRegistryType.RegType_Configuration); }
}
```